# Celery tasks to update two databases

Tags: mysql, django, mongodb, celery

We have two micro services. one with django and mysql for user actions and another one with bottle and mongodb for geo calculations.

From the background we need to update/look at both mysql and mongodb. How can we do this in celery ? 
tasks can be execute from Django app or bottle app.

Thanks.

Comment: yes it can be done with celery.   You'll need a broker to handle the celery tasks and a worker.   Que two separate jobs one for each dB and you should be good to go

Comment: what is the best way to do update the mongodb with celery ? I didnt find any good soltions with mongodb and celery ? ok. but how can we keep consistence in two tasks updates. I need to update mysql first and update mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 celery taskes. 
You'll need a broker.

For Mysql that is well documented. 
Use https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/python/ to connect to the mogodb and update the record.

Link the two tasks together.
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/canvas.html#chains

Set up celery to do exponential retries.   Will help avoid the thundering herd problem. 
[Increase celery retry time each retry cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470089/increase-celery-retry-time-each-retry-cycle)